# Why is the strain independent of the type of material (in beam bending)?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, structural-beam

When a beam is bended, the strain that is produced above and below the neutral axis is proportional to the curvature of the beam and varies linearly with the distance from the neutral axis.

But why is the strain independent of the type of material?

Formula: (I understand the derivation of it)

$\epsilon = - k$  $y$

$\epsilon$ is strain , $k$ is the curvature, and $y$ is the distance from the neutral axis.

Comment: In this context Strain is a measure of displacement, just a definition that’s all. The amount of strain for a given stress or force would change with the material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Claudio Saspinski and @UVphoton say "strain" is a purely purely gemetric description of the displacement of the material. The material-dependent elastic properties are what link the displacement to the "stress" or applied force. It's not *exactly* true that the strain is independent of the materail however. [Poisson's ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_ratio) is one of the material-dependent elastic constants and it affects whether the bottom of the beam gets wider or narrower as the beam bends downwards.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to imagine situations where it is not followed. For example, a hose normally deforms in a way that tends to flatten the bent region, changing its cross section.

But the model described by the OP is followed by most real situations, and in that cases the strain is defined that way. What depends on the material is the resulting stress.

Comment: Thank you everyone.